# How to mock $window.top and $window.self?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, iframe, karma-jasmine

In my controller, I am checking if page is iframed or not by this condition:

```
var vm = this;
if ($window.self !== $window.top) {
    //We are iframed
    vm.weAreIFramed = true
}
else {
    vm.weAreIFramed = false;
}
```

I want to write a unit test for it. I wrote something like this but the test is always failing:

```
var homeController, $httpBackend, $controller, $location, $rootScope;
var topObj = {};
var selfObj = {};
var windowObj = {
    location: { href: '' },
    top: topObj,
    self: topObj
};

beforeEach(module("app"), function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', windowObj);
});

beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _$controller_, _$location_, _$rootScope_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $location = _$location_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    homeController = $controller("homeController");
}));

afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

it("vm.weAreIFramed should be false if we are not iFramed", function () {
    console.log(angular.mock.dump(windowObj));
    expect(homeController.weAreIFramed).toEqual(false);
});
```

It fails with below error:

[image]

How to write the correct test to check if the page is iframed or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test fails because `"" === ""`. In real `window`, `top` and `self` are objects.

It should be

```
var topObj = {};
var selfObj = {};
var windowObj = {
    location: { href: '' },
    top: topObj,
    self: selfObj
};
```

And for the other condition, only `topObj` can be specified for both.

Comment: I implemented above changes but the test still fails.

Comment: How exactly does it fail? What is error message? The code above is enough is enough to mock $window props the way you want. A controller isn't instantiated in original code, for starters. The test itself can fail for countless reasons that didn't appear in the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I see the problem. You have `beforeEach(module("app"), function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', windowObj);
});`. A function is not a part of a module and isn't used anywhere. This results in using original $window. You can check it with `expect($window).not.toBe(window)`. It should be `beforeEach(module("app", function ($provide) {...}))` Or better `beforeEach(module("app", { $window: windowObj }))`.